# How to scale and rotate smoothly?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview, uiimageview

I have seen some app, they are able to scale and rotate the image at the same time. It does not require to release the finger touch.

My following code require to:
1. Touch to scale
2. Release
3. Touch to rotate

How do i scale and rotate at the same time?

In my main code:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *imagePanGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveImage:)];
[imagePanGesture setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[imagePanGesture setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
[tempImageView addGestureRecognizer:imagePanGesture]; 

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scaleImage:)];
[tempImageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];  

UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationGesture = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotateImage:)];
[tempImageView addGestureRecognizer:rotationGesture];
```

In individual scale and rotate

```
- (void)scaleImage:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
    if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
    {
        previousScale = 1.0;
        return;
    }

    CGFloat newScale = 1.0 - (previousScale - [recognizer scale]);

    CGAffineTransform currentTransformation = [recognizer view].transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransformation, newScale, newScale);

    [[recognizer view] setTransform:newTransform];
    previousScale = [recognizer scale];
}

- (void)rotateImage:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
    if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {


            previousRotation = 0.0;
            return;
        }

        CGFloat newRotation = 0.0 - (previousRotation - [recognizer rotation]);

        CGAffineTransform currentTransformation = [recognizer view].transform;
        CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransformation, newRotation);

        [[recognizer view] setTransform:newTransform];

        previousRotation = [recognizer rotation];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may check this http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is

[-gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer%3ashouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer%3a)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you are looking for... Add this method to your `.m` file.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```